# mySQL: Why is if(condition,then,'') != '' not the same as if(condition,then,0) != 0

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement, substring

I just encountered something I can't explain when doing some queries on my mySQL database:

```
SELECT
if(LENGTH(partner_id) > 38, SUBSTRING(partner_id FROM 8), 0) as sub_id
from people
Where
if(LENGTH(partner_id) > 38, SUBSTRING(partner_id FROM 8), 0) != 0
```

That's nothing special so far, I only want to display a part of some partner_ids.
But if I do the same statement slightly different (exhange the 0 with empty string ''):

```
SELECT
if(LENGTH(partner_id) > 38, SUBSTRING(partner_id FROM 8), '') as sub_id
from people
Where
if(LENGTH(partner_id) > 38, SUBSTRING(partner_id FROM 8), '') != ''
```

I get way more results. Only difference: I put an empty string in the *else-statement* and compare the empty string. Is this some strange behaviour of the SUBSTRING function? Or do I miss the wood for the trees?

Comment: What values are in the partner_ID?

Comment: number and hash-combinations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One explanation is that you have some partner ids where the substring starts with a `0`.

In the first case, the query is doing an integer comparison.  A string like '0a' evaluates to "0" as an integer.  This is equal to 0, so they are filtered out.

In the second case, the query is doing a string comparison.  A string like '0a' is different from '', so these pass the filtering clause.

Comment: Sounds like this must be the problem.  Here is a sql fiddle demonstrating:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/16b74/1/0

Comment: I think that is the problem. Sounds pretty simple if you think about it but good to know that 0a = 0 because of differences in integer and string comparison. So my conclusion is that string comparison is more bulletproof than integer comparison.